# running nginx, uwsgi, bottle on ec2 micro instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, bottle

I am trying to setup nginx, uwsgi, bottle.py on an ec2 micro instance. So far I've installed the components and nginx is working correctly serving up a test index.html page. If I stop the nginx server and run a test bottle app on python's internal development server, it also works.

However, my uwsgi isn't working. This is my "default" file in etc/nginx/site-enabled/. I am using an elastic ip (xx.xx.xx.xx) attached to my micro instance.

```
upstream _bottle {
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
    root /var/www/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @uwsgi;
    }

    location @uwsgi {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass _bottle;
    }
}
```

And here is my uwsgi config file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/app
master = true
plugins = python
file = index.py
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
```

I've also made sure to:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app
```

When I restart nginx and uwsgi and go to the elastic ip address with my browser, I get nginx's bad gateway page.

The nginx error log is giving me:

```
*1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client.....
```

I've read that "upstream prematurely closed" error is indicative to memory/cpu/resource problems? Does that have something to do with using the micro instance and not having enough resources? But the only person that's accessing this micro instance through the browser is me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're missing the `socket` directive in your uwsgi config file. Your setup is incorrect.

NGINX passes the request to the uWSGI process on a channel. It could be a network socket or a file socket (named pipe).
You didn't configure this channel.

In your uwsgi config declare a file socket like

```
socket = /tmp/bottle.socket
```

And in your nginx configuration use that socket for the upstream:

```
upstream _bottle {
    server unix:/tmp/bottle.socket;
}
```

and also remember to pass uwsgi params in your location directive

```
include uwsgi_params;
```

For more information refer to the [official documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html)